# Запрос в строке браузера, для получения только нужной информации из XML

Tags: xml, http, https, xmlhttprequest, xmlparser

Есть запрос API, который выдает конкретные поля всех ценных бумаг ММВБ, я хочу получить или отобразить укороченный список бумаг для которых поле SECTYPE=J или E, возможно ли это сделать с помощью запроса?

https://iss.moex.com/iss/engines/stock/markets/shares/securities.xml?iss.meta=off&iss.only=securities&securities.columns=SECID,SECNAME,FACEUNIT,SECTYPE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если тут https://iss.moex.com/iss/reference/ не описана такая возможность, то в общем случае нельзя.

Но можно отфильтровать. Сделать хтмл-страничку, в ней поле для ввода апи адреса и после получения хмл-файла целиком вывести выпадающие  списки с набором всех данных для фильтрации. После выбора параметров удалить все ненужное и вывести требуемое.

Страничку можно тупо на раб. столе держать.

Но мне сдается что такое же можно в текстовом процессоре делать (в экселе, таблицах опен/либре офиса).